# VS Code, changing how Flake8 warnings/errors are displayer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I started using VS Code for Python development, and I'm trying to figure out how to configure Flake8 properly.

I installed the extension:

[image]

And I wanted to configure it so that all the problems detected by it are indicated by a yellow squiggly line.
I added the following lines to my user settings (on MacOS, the file in Users/my_user_name/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json):

```
"python.linting.flake8CategorySeverity.E": "Warning",
"python.linting.flake8CategorySeverity.F": "Warning",
"python.linting.flake8CategorySeverity.W": "Warning",
```

but it's still highlighting warning and errors differently:

[image]

I don't know if this is possible in the first place, but I have the feeling the lines regarding flake8 are being ignored...I tried adding

```
"python.linting.enabled": false,
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": false,
```

but the problems are still being highlighted, the only way to avoid it seems to be disabling the extension altogether.

My workspace setting file is empty, so nothing should be overwriting the user settings, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension specific settings should be used:

```
"flake8.severity": {
    "E": "Warning",
    "F": "Warning",
    "I": "Information",
    "W": "Warning"
}
```

Available settings are listed in extension description.